# Sequential row selection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, select, row

I am both new to the forum and to VBA (for excel).

I am trying to do a very simple thing:

- I have a dataset of 1500 lines--> 150 companies each having yearly observations for 10 years.
- I need to add one more line (i.e. one more year) at the beginning of each subset.

So to avoid typing ALT+H+I+R 150 times (and also because I´ll probably encounter the same issue in the future) I am trying out VBA.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub InsertRows()
' InsertRows Macro

Dim Var As Integer
Var = 5
Do While Var < 1700
    Var = Var + 10
    Range("F" & Var).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
Loop

End Sub
```

The problem I have is that the program "falls behind" by one Row for each repetition given that a new row is added with each loop.

I would greatly appreciate your input!

Thx!
Eliseo

Comment: just add 1 more to your var after you add the row.

Comment: Also I would remove the part where you select and then insert and just put `rows(var).entirerow.insert`

Comment: @Histerical - Ahh, music to my ears :)  (...err, eyes I suppose.)

Comment: Thank you very much for both proposed solutions, they work perfectly. Much appreciated! Happy weekend to everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this get you any closer:

```
Sub InsertRows()
    Dim Var As Long
    Var = 1700
    Do While Var > 10
        Var = Var - 10
        Range("F" & Var).EntireRow.Insert
    Loop
End Sub
```

You may have to change to starting row to get the desired spacing

Comment: I also recommend [not using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). I know you're probably just trying to fix OP's issue, while keeping his style, but I think it's simple enough to explain (with his example), and it is certainly best practice.

Comment: @BruceWayne  I completely agree with you ! ......................I am really more concerned with the exact spacing of the added rows.

Comment: @BruceWayne  Suggestion adopted !!